# Question related to Bayes theorem

Tags: bayes-theorem

I spent some times on [this website](http://www.sports-management-degrees.com/baseball/) trying to figure out how Bayes Theorem works.

Now, from that example, consider The Yankees has a 72% of winning next game based on previous results. When someone (named Bob in the example) predicts a game, he has 55% of choosing the proper winner.

The following formula is being used to know that, combining the win percentage and Bob's prediction, the actual winning chances for the Yankees now are 76% :

$$
p(A_1|B) = \frac {(0.72*0.55)} {(0.72*0.55)+(0.28*0.45)} = 0.76
$$

I just don't get how Bob's accuracy has to do with anything in that... It feel like, the better Bob is getting, the better the Yankees can win... You know what I mean ?

Let me show some stupid example, if Bob's prediction are based on 10 predictions and they were 100% correct.

$$
p(A_1|B) = \frac {(0.72*1)} {(0.72*1)+(0.28*0)} = 1
$$

Now Yankees cannot lose. Where is the mistake here ?

Comment: You can only run this calculation provided that Bob has a 55% (or 100% for the second calculation) chance of success in predicting a game that *hasn't happened yet*. Extrapolation is never safe.

Comment: @Ian Yes but what if his 55% prediction is changed to 100% accurary for him ? The game hasn't happened yet but the new prediction would be 100% win for the Yankees ?

Comment: Sure, if he's always right and he predicts the Yankees will win then the Yankees will win. But he can't be always right unless the game is somehow rigged. Anyway, going back to the more realistic scenario, if the prior probability that the Yankees win is 72% and Bob (who is better than 50/50 at predicting games) predicts they will win, then the posterior probability that the Yankees win (after taking into account Bob's prediction) is higher. That's to be expected, because his predictions "have merit".

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much for your help. It seems so strange to me that someone betting could improve the team's chances of winning the game... I have a very simple prediction model and I would like to add my own prediction skills (based on my past predictions) in the formula...

Comment: With something like this the frequentist model is a bit of a problem because there is only one game to talk about. There is no real sense in "re-running" the game multiple independent times. The Bayesian perspective is helpful in these cases: it says that when you learn that Bob predicts that the Yankees will win, you should update your belief system in favor of them winning, in accordance with the Bayes rule. That is because as I said, his predictions have merit (also according to your belief system).

Comment: @Ian What if my system tells me that Team A will have a 60% chances of winning and Team B therefore 40%. My accuracy being 10%. If I apply the above formula, both teams are going to have very low chances of winning, do you know what I mean ?

Comment: No, I don't. You have to make a prediction one way or the other. If $A$ means "team A wins", $B$ means "team B wins", $P_A$ means "you predict team A wins", and $P_B$ means "you predict team $B$ wins", then $P(A \mid P_A)+P(B \mid P_A)=1$ and $P(A \mid P_B)+P(B \mid P_B)=1$. (I assume ties are not an option in this game. If they are, put in a corresponding term for ties.) You are right that $P(A \mid P_A)+P(B \mid P_B)$ could be less than $1$ but there is no contradiction there because these are probabilities calculated assuming different information.

Comment: @Ian What bugs me is that, let's say I find that Team A has 60% of win. Team B has therefore 40%. 60%+40% is 100% which is correct to me. Now, if I use the formula used in my question (for both Team A and Team B) with a prediction accuracy of 10%, Team A will have around 14% chances of win and Team B will be around 6%. 14+6% = 20% which is wrong... It should still be 100%... Is it better explained ? I guess I have to understand that if my Team A has 16% chances of win, THEN Team B has 100-16=84% of chances of win, using the formula on both Team would lead to wrong results...

Comment: I did explain this already. You're "adding apples to oranges". It only really makes sense to add probabilities which are conditioned on the same set of information. Thus $P(A \mid P_A)+P(B \mid P_B)$ is not really a meaningful quantity. You are adding the probability that you are right when you predict A wins to the probability that you are right when you predict B wins, but the scenarios being assumed are not the same.

Comment: @Ian : thank you for your help.